# Can you help me with this while loop?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have this program:

```
n = []
m = []

name = input("Enter student's names (separated by using commas) : ")
mark = input("Enter student's marks (separated by using commas) : ")
(n.append(name))
(m.append(mark))

total = 0
index = 0
while index < len(name) :
    print("name:",name[index],'mark:',mark[index])
    index +=1
```

and it came out like this:

```
Enter student's names (separated by using commas) : a,s,d
Enter student's marks (separated by using commas) : 1,2,3
name: a mark: 1
name: , mark: ,
name: s mark: 2
name: , mark: ,
name: d mark: 3
```

How to make it only come out like this:

```
Enter student's names (separated by using commas) : a,s,d
Enter student's marks (separated by using commas) : 1,2,3
name: a mark: 1
name: s mark: 2
name: d mark: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make name and mark as array's using split function.

```
name = input("Enter student's names (separated by using commas) : ")
mark = input("Enter student's marks (separated by using commas) : ")

name = name.split(',')
mark = mark.split(',')
total = 0
index = 0
while index < len(name) :
    print("name:",name[index],'mark:',mark[index])
    index +=1
```

Output

```
$ python3 test.py 
Enter student's names (separated by using commas) : as,we,re
Enter student's marks (separated by using commas) : 1,2,3
name: as mark: 1
name: we mark: 2
name: re mark: 3
```

If you want to maintain your empty lists, here is what you should do:

```
n = []
m = []
name = input("Enter student's names (separated by using commas) : ")
mark = input("Enter student's marks (separated by using commas) : ")
(n.extend(name.split(',')))
(m.extend( mark.split(',')))
total = 0
index = 0
while index < len(n) :
    print("name:",n[index],'mark:',m[index])
    index +=1
```

Comment: yes it work...thanks....but the question ask to create an empty list first...and i dont know how to remove the comma

Comment: I suppose your are creating empty list n and m and are trying to append comma separated values to it ?